# Bootstrap - does all 'rows' MUST be followed with a column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is a silly question, but I can't seem to find an answer on the net for this. For bootstrap, I know you use rows and cols to specify the size of the row. But if I have something like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'></div>
</div>
```

Is there any point in adding that `col-md-12`? I would of thought just sticking the `row` class is enough if you wanted the full length of the row??

Any advice on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A `.row` and a `.col-X-X` are different things. Yes, you will need the column + a row. If you use Bootstrap 4, you can just use the `.col` class whereas in Bootstrap 3 you must use `.col-X-12` for full width. From the docs `Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.
The negative margin is why the examples below are outdented. It's so that content within grid columns is lined up with non-grid content.`

Comment: Yes, you probaly want the `col`.  Inspect it with your browser's developer tools.  You'll see margin and other styling gets applied to `col` to get things to line up properly.

Comment: @cale_b That's the thing, I tried both and i cannot see any difference so far...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you probaly want the col. Inspect it with your browser's developer tools. You'll see margin /padding and other styling gets applied to `.col-*` to get things to line up properly.

The `.row` class primarily provides the "float clearing" that columns provide.

Columns as you know allow for a variety of "grid layout" widths / sizes, and automatically adjust to responsive browser size needs.

Run the snippet below to see the difference (click the "Full Page" link, otherwise it's compressed into a small view).  (Note that I've added borders to rows / cols to highlight what's going on):

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.other {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      This is a row with a full-width column.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      This row has a few smaller column.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      This row has a few smaller column.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      This row has a few smaller column.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    This row has no columns.
  </div>
  <div class="other">This has no columns nor rows.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a full width row couldn't you just omit **both** the `.row` and the `.col-`? seems like unnecessary markup.

Comment: Technically, yes, however that's contrary to bootstrap's design.  I personally have started to use bootstrap _quite a bit less_ because I think it often requires a lot of unnecessary markup.

Comment: I understand but to me it seems like you should only need to use a `.row` when you actually have columns (on any viewport)... no benefit just extra markup to maintain

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, you have a good answer and I have upvoted it. I just dont agree that you have to use row and col for a full-width content area on all viewports. Bootstrap grid is great at what it does, but just use it when you really need it is all I am saying. Also, I don't see how you _lose the intended functionality of bootstrap_ when you do this.

Comment: Agreed.  That's why I added it to the snippet, to demonstrate how it looks / feels without either a row or col!

Comment: In bootstrap 5, all children elements of a `.row` class are assumed to be `.col-12`.  So they will behave how you expect, but in bs3 (sample above), they do not behave the same as the snippet demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

A `.row` and a `.col-X-X` are different things. Yes, you will need the column + a row. 
If you use Bootstrap 4, you can just use the `.col` class whereas in Bootstrap 3 you must use `.col-X-12` for full width.

From the [bootstrap 3 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-intro)

> 1) Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.
>
> 2) The negative margin is why the examples below are outdented. **It's so that content within grid columns is lined up with non-grid content.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want your row to be 100% width, then there is no need to have a .col div within your .row div. However, having one is useful if you want the default Bootstrap .col styling to be applied to it (such as padding and margin).

Comment: Technically accurate, but missing some important relevant details.  This is only true if you have _no rows_ that contain columns.